# Asp.Net - Error Number:1505 - update database doesn't work

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm not able to update the database since I made some changes to a model, however, even those changes have been removed the error remained. How can I fix this?

```
    PM> update-database
Build started...
Build succeeded.
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (3ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IX_Salaries_UserId] ON [Salaries] ([UserId]);
Failed executing DbCommand (3ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IX_Salaries_UserId] ON [Salaries] ([UserId]);
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.Salaries' and the index name 'IX_Salaries_UserId'. The duplicate key value is (1).
The statement has been terminated.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean isAsync, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String methodName)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
ClientConnectionId:831f2e07-8517-4158-8417-72657d6cd583
Error Number:1505,State:1,Class:16
The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.Salaries' and the index name 'IX_Salaries_UserId'. The duplicate key value is (1).
The statement has been terminated.


    migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
        name: "IX_Salaries_UserId",
        table: "Salaries",
        column: "UserId",
        unique: true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the duplicate key in your table `[Salaries]` column `[UserId]` to be able to create a unique index on that table.

the error says that you have two salaries with the same `UserId` (1)